# Tool to combine different CSS files

Tags: css, file, overriding

I have few different files and I would like to combine them into one with overriding unnecessary properties. Think it like this:

file1.css

```
.selector {
    color: red;
    background: white;
}
```

file2.css

```
.selector {
    color: green;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Output

```
.selector {
    color: green;
    background: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

The difference is the color property on file1 is removed because the second file overrides it. Is there a tool to do this? I've found [this tool](http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor/combine) but it doesn't work (probably it's outdated and doesn't cover all browser-wide properties).

Answer (score 0):

I've found following websites which do the job. But they take 1 input. It shouldn't be hard to combine them in a text editor anyway.

http://refresh-sf.com/

https://cssminifier.com/

The output is identical if you don't change settings.